# How to emulate Android's productFlavors in a pure java gradle module?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need three flavors:

- `fake`
- `staging`
- `prod`

`fake` will provide classes like `FakeUser`, `FakeUserDb` - it's very important that these classes are *not* compiled into the `prod` flavor.

`prod` and `staging` are completely identical, except that I need to compile a different `String url` into `prod` vs `staging`.

So, I need to create an "abstract" `real` flavor that both `prod` and `staging` inherit.

This can be easily done with the android gradle plugin, but how can I do it in a pure java gradle module?

Comment: Are you sure that these cannot be build types? AFAIK, build types are a Gradle thing that the Android Plugin for Gradle happens to leverage.

Comment: oh they can definitely be buildTypes. In android plugin terminology I just need stagingDebug, prodRelease, and fakeDebug

Comment: @CommonsWare so `buildType` is a gradle concept - not just an android plugin concept? is there any documentation on it for pure java? every google search seems to lead me to the android plugin

Comment: Hrm. I could have sworn that `debug` and `release` came from Gradle. I'm not finding information about that now either. My apologies.

Comment: @CommonsWare there seems to be whispers of gradle supporting these things outside the android plugin, but no real documentation on it.

Comment: maybe this is it? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_software.html

Comment: Possibly, though that seems to be a work in progress.

Answer (score 6):

For each flavour you'll want to

1. Create a [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) so it will be compiled
2. Make the `${flavour}Compile` [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html) extend the main `compile` configuration (see table 45.6 [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) for the configurations per SourceSet created by the java plugin)
3. Create a [JarTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) (using the flavour as a classifier)
4. [Publish the jar artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) so the flavour can be referenced via the [classifier](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:classifiers)

Something like:

```
def flavours = ['fake', 'staging', 'prod']
flavours.each { String flavour ->
    SourceSet sourceSet = sourceSets.create(flavour)
    sourceSet.java {
       srcDirs 'src/main/java', "src/$flavour/java"
    }
    sourceSet.resources {
       srcDirs 'src/main/resources', "src/$flavour/resources"
    }
    Task jarTask = tasks.create(name: "${flavour}Jar", type: Jar) {
       from sourceSet.output
       classifier flavour
    }
    configurations.getByName("${flavour}Compile").extendsFrom configurations.compile
    configurations.getByName("${flavour}CompileOnly").extendsFrom configurations.compileOnly
    configurations.getByName("${flavour}CompileClasspath").extendsFrom configurations.compileClasspath
    configurations.getByName("${flavour}Runtime").extendsFrom configurations.runtime

    artifacts {
       archives jarTask
    }
    assemble.dependsOn jarTask
}
```

Then, to reference one of the flavours in another project you could do one of the following:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(path: ':someProject', configuration: 'fakeCompile')
   compile project(path: ':someProject', configuration: 'fakeRuntime')
   compile 'someGroup:someProject:1.0:fake'
   compile group: 'someGroup', name: 'someProject', version: '1.0', classifier: 'fake'
}
```

Comment: while this is helpful, this is only sourceSets. It doesn't get into configurations, and making certain gradle modules dependent on another module's configuration

Comment: Updated the second solution to include an artifact for each flavour (with unique classifier) and wired it into the DAG. These artifacts can then be included in downstream projects (by specifying a classifier)

Comment: Great, thank you! How does consuming those jar artifacts work? Say if you were consuming that jar from a sibling gradle module?

Comment: Tweaked slightly to create a configuration per flavour and added example references

Comment: thank you! this is working well, except that my `fake`/`prod`/`staging` configurations don't have access to any third party libraries that I declare in the dependencies block. meaning `main` has access to `dependencies { compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion" }`, but `fake`, `staging`, `prod` do not have rxjava compiled onto its classpath. How do you fix this?

Comment: More specifically, I'm getting `package rx does not exist` when running `:someProject:fakeClasses`, but `:someProject:classes` compiles with no problems.

Comment: Added `config.extendsFrom(configurations.runtime)`

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately the same errors still get thrown. by manually adding a configuration block in the following gist, I fix those errors and `:server:fakeClasses` compiles, but I would prefer a less manual approach. https://gist.github.com/ZakTaccardi/af96c5bbed048b9465c5fa3db19cfe0b

Comment: I said to use `:xxx:fake` and NOT `:xxx:fakeClasses`. If you want to add extra configurations, do it within my loop. I also said config.extendsFrom(configurations.runtime) not compile

Comment: `Task 'fake' is ambiguous in project ':server'. Candidates are: 'fakeClasses', 'fakeJar'.` Both `:fakeClasses` and `fakeJar` fail with missing 3rd party dependencies. This is before I reference my `fake` configuration in another module like a `:client` module

Comment: The [JavaPlugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) creates a "${flavour}Compile" configuration for each flavour. I've added an extra `afterEvaluate` block to make each extend from `compile`. This will also flow into ${flavour}CompileOnly and ${flavour}Runtime etc.

Comment: thanks! I don't think you need to use that `afterEvaluate{}` block at all -- see my updated gist for a working solution

Comment: So, it's working? If it were me I'd replace ${config.name} with $flavour for consistency

Comment: works beautifully! if you update your answer with these final changes, I'll accept it! thank you for all your help

Comment: Slight change, please try again. I'm pretty sure you only need to configure the `${flavour}Compile` configuration as `${flavour}CompileOnly` and `${flavour}Runtime` will extend from this. See Table 45.6 [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management). Note: I removed the `$flavour` configuration since there's already `${flavour}Compile` and `${flavour}Runtime`. Note: `compile project(name: 'someProject', configuration: 'fakeCompile')`

Comment: Because you have `${flavor}Compile` extend `compile` AFTER `${flavour}CompileOnly` and ${flavour}Runtime` are created, I don't think it works that way unfortunately. If I get ride of `configurations.getByName("${flavor.name}CompileOnly").extendsFrom(configurations.compileOnly)`, I get compilation errors for my `compileOnly` dependencies

Comment: ok, extended for al 4 source set configurations, it can't hurt anyway. Please try it out and mark as accepted if it works. This is a good candidate for a gradle plugin :)

Comment: @ZakTaccardi do you know if this solution still works for the las gradle version? I have a project with the same structure but I'm not able to make it work following this example. I get an unresolved reference error:  the code from my java module placed in a flavour directory cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a gradle-java-flavours plugin to do this:

- [github project](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours)
- [JavaFlavoursPlugin.groovy](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursPlugin.groovy)
- [JavaFlavoursPluginTest.groovy](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursPluginTest.groovy)